# Android. ImageVIew ->Scaling Animation -> ViewPager

Tags: android, ui

Например, если в клиенте VK на андроид, кликнуть по картинке в посте, где несколько картинок, то эта картинка увеличивается, затемняется фон, и теперь картинки можно листать. Каким образом такое реализуется?

Comment: Предполагал что делается так - картинка удаляется с места, создается ViewPager, куда картинка вставляется в то же место, далее уже все просто=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше всего разобрать приложение и покопаться в коде.
Но я предполагаю, что делается так:
 - Сначала ImageView скалируется
 - Когда анимация закончилась, открывается диалоговое окно(full screen) с ViewPager
 - при закрытии происходят обратные действия.